# Creating Map Book with face to face pages showing before and after digitizations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, data-driven-pages

I want to create a mapbook that displays changes in river flows over time. I have one shapefile of my recent digitizations, as well as ones done prior. I was hoping to display them, new on the left and old on the right.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - in the Online Help there is documentation on [Creating a map book with facing pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000002p000000) with a Python script you can adapt to do this.

At first glance this may seem like it is an unrelated requirement to deal only with book "gutters".

However, the key thing is that left and right pages use different MXDs, and in your case those will be the "new" and "old" MXDs.

Comment: HA! I was just going around that forever today. Thank you